# C# regex составить регулярное выражение

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо составить регулярное выражение для входной строки, вот моя попытка:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\A[pPrRnNbBqQkK][a-zA-Z][1-8]-[a-zA-Z][1-8][pPrRnNbBqQkK]*");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итак, из чего должна состоять строка, которую я собираюсь проверять: первая буква p, r, n, b, q или k в верхнем или нижнем регистре, дальше идет буква в диапазоне a-h в в. или н. регистре, дальше цифра от 1 до 8, дальше "-", потом опять буква a-h и цифра 1-8 и в конце **необязательная** буква prnbq в в. или н. регистре

Пожалуйста, помогите исправить мою попытку.

Comment: ну кстати оно почти работает, по крайней мере на "Pa2-a4" не ругается, но вот на "Pa3-a5q" ругается, как я понимаю что-то в конце регулярки перепутал?

Comment: https://regex101.com

Comment: Также обратите внимание на [a-zA-Z] и [a-hA-H]

Comment: `(?i)^[prnbqk][a-h][1-8]-[a-h][1-8][prnbqk]?$`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте

```cs
(?i)^[prnbqk][a-h][1-8]-[a-h][1-8][prnbqk]?$
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fi%29%5E%5Bprnbqk%5D%5Ba-h%5D%5B1-8%5D-%5Ba-h%5D%5B1-8%5D%5Bprnbqk%5D%3F%5Cr%3F%24&i=Pa2-a4%0D%0APa3-a5q&o=m).

*Подробности*

- `(?i)` - регистронезависимый поиск
- `^` - начало строки
- `[prnbqk]` - буква из набора `prnbqk`
- `[a-h]` - буква от `a` до `h`
- `[1-8]` - цифра от 1 до 8
- `-` - дефис
- `[a-h]` - буква от `a` до `h`
- `[1-8]` - цифра от 1 до 8
- `[prnbqk]?` - необязательная буква из набора `prnbqk`
- `$` - конец строки.

Comment: да, все так, оказывается и моя регулярка работала, ругалось на код ниже регулярки, а не на нее, в любом случае спасибо! Подскажите, "?" и "*" работают одинаково, то есть обозначают что последний символ необязателен или есть какая-то разница?

Comment: @Pekor `?` - **один или ноль**, `*` - **ноль и более (как можно больше)** повторов.